# how to drop the title for data-frame columns

Tags: python, pandas

I come up with a dataframe like this, I wonder how can we change or drop the 'id' and 'date' as they are just the names for index and columns.

```
id               col1        col2       clo3  
date                                          
2000-01-03  55.500000         NaN        NaN  
2000-01-04  52.812500         NaN        NaN  
2000-01-05  52.750000         NaN        NaN  
2000-01-06  53.500000         NaN        NaN  
2000-01-07  53.625000         NaN        NaN  
2000-01-10  52.656250         NaN        NaN
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Option 1**
`rename_axis`

```
df.rename_axis(None, 1, inplace=True)  # 1 is for axis=1
```

---

**Option 2**
reassign `df.columns`

```
df.columns = df.columns.tolist()
```

---

**Option 3**
Setting the `name` attribute, as [described by Boud](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40749533/4909087).

```
df.columns.name = None
df.index.name = None
```

Answer (score 2):

These variables are represented through the `name` property:

```
df.columns.name = None
df.index.name = None
```